# Twig functions count & group

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, twig

I am using Mongodb with Symfony.
I have a list of building with rooms, how can I count the rooms in my db and group them by type? at the moment I can list all rooms type but some of them are duplicated.
I saw lenght function but it seems that it counts the caracters not the number of rooms.
Here is the query to fecth data :

```
$room= $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                ->getManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder(\Pms\PmsBundle\Document\Hotel\hotels::class)
                ->find()
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();
```

Here is the code I am using to display room types :

```
{% for j in i.rooms %}
{% if j.roomfloor < 6  %}
    {{ j.roomtype }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: twig function count als the length of arrays, can you post some code of what you are trying to do

Comment: I edited my question with the query and the twig code. With that code I get a list of room types, but I don't want to display the duplicated room type. And ofcours I want to count them.

Comment: you need to create a new twig function in it you gonna call the array_unique() Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work for your ORM not for Twig.
Group By into your queryBuilder with a count and only after present your data into Twig.